# Multiple External Internet Providers - Edge Router?

Tags: networking, router

I have the desire for the following type of configuration below. I want to combine internet providers, but want to make sure all traffic non natted gets through to the Comcast connection, I am assuming that I can do all this fine with the router, looking for advise here if you have any.

But with the (Ubiquity) Edge Router, is it possible to assign out to other routers, and edge servers one of the dedicated IP's? Is there any advise here?

[image]

Comment: I’m assuming both ATT and Comcast modems are in bridge mode. I think some complication here is that you are trying to “pass through” a public IP to a private device. That’s not really how a router works. Typically you really only need one router with 3 interfaces. 1 interface each for ATT and Comcast with the public IPs assigned to those interfaces. Then a third interface connecting to one internal network. With a series of NAT and routing rules you can direct all traffic on one particular public IP to one particular server. But all internal devices still have private IPs. No “pass through.”

Comment: It’s called one-to-one NAT.  An internal server has IP 10.0.0.2 and is connected through one-to-one NAT to public IP 1.1.1.2. All outbound traffic from 10.0.0.2 is NATd to 1.1.1.2 and all inbound traffic destined to 1.1.1.2 is NATd to 10.0.0.2. The internal server never sees the IP 1.1.1.2.